# Matching named anchor hash in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am looking for docs/info on how to correctly match/handle named anchor hash tags in UI Router routes. Not looking for scrolling but simply having the route be able to be reloaded and match such as `/#about` match my '/' route.  I've played around with some regex without success. It seems there was a merged [pull request](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/95b16bf21a9922d07aade73adec58feb4fbb74df) to handle this as some point but cannot find info on how to let the router handle a browser reload with the hash tag.

How do I make the following match when calling something such as `/#about`?

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',    
  })
```

Right now loading `http://localhost:8000/#about` in the browser directly causes a page not found error. I would like it to a) keep the URL as is (i.e. not strip the hash off) ideally and b) have it and any possible named anchor match the home route.

Here are two GH issues ([612](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/612), [510](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/510)) but I am not clear if it was ever resolved and what flag/option needs to be enabled.

I am on Angular 1.4.x with HTML5 mode enabled.

Comment: @charlietfl added some more notes

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by combining a few of the utilities provided in angular ui router. You will have to tweak the services a bit, but you get $state, $location, and $urlMatcherFactory, get all the states and then filter the array down to the one that matches the current url. You then make a UrlMatcher against the url, passing in the matched parameters and then navigate to the state. I tried $urlRouter.sync but it just would not work.

```
        if (!this.$state.current.name) {
            var allStates = this.$state.get(), loc = this.$location.path(), search = this.$location.search(), matcherFact = this.$urlMatcherFactory, matchedParams;
            var myCurrentState = allStates.filter(function(stateObj){
                if(stateObj.abstract){
                    return false;
                }
               var url = stateObj.url;
               var matcher = matcherFact.compile(url);
               var isMatch = matcher.exec(loc, search);
               if(isMatch){
                   matchedParams = isMatch;
               }
               return isMatch || null;     
            });
            var stateToGo = myCurrentState[0];
            if(stateToGo){
                this.$state.go(stateToGo.name, matchedParams);
            } else {
               window.location.reload(true);
            }

        }
```